# Improving performance of a python scirpt with many imports

Tags: python, performance, package

I have built a script that uses about 15 imported packages, and that takes too long (~45secs). The packages are essential, in the sense that I cannot remove them. I have done selective imports like: from x import y, z , but it didnt help by much. Is there a way to import many packages but have the script run fast?

Comment: No. It makes no difference if you import selected methods (or otherwise) vs. Importing the whole thing. The burden is only incurred once, though, because imported modules will be cached after that, so if you had a continuous script, the import time wouldn't be relevant

Comment: you can import 1000000s of libraries in 45 seconds .... its not the imports that are your problem... its whats happening inside them ... all logic should be enclosed in `if __name__ == "__main__":` wrappers etc ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley these imports are not my own, they are quite popular packages (numpy, pandas ect) that I suppose have this matter solved

Comment: can you show these 15 packages that seem to take 45 seconds to import? (pandas can certainly take a little bit of time... not a whole lot... it should not take almost a minute to import commonly used packages... maybe on some very very very weak computing platform))